# serial port writing "ReadIntervalTimeout" hanging

Tags: c, file-io, serial-port

I'm writing a code to read a few bytes from serial port and write to the same port asynchronously. The sending code runs continuously in the main() and i start a new thread to read from it. initially I had problems with reading a frame from a hardware device connected to serial port. The problem was because the readFile() timeout between two bytes was set to MAXDWORD. So, i recieved incomplete bytes. So i changed the ReadIntervalTimeout = MAXDWORD to ReadIntervalTimeout=20. then the receiving of full frames worked. But then, the sending of bytes is hanging. 
  As i knew reading and writing a serial port was completely independent. Or is it not? The file is configured as Non-overlapping(set to 0) Please let me know if any more details are required.

1) These are the COMMTIMEOUTS settings

```
Cptimeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout         = MAXDWORD; //changed  to 20 for a gap of 20ms 
Cptimeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier  = 0;
Cptimeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant    = 0;
Cptimeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0;
Cptimeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant   = 0;
```

2) This is the send() running in the main()

```
while(1)
{
   int RS232_SendBuf(int comport_number, unsigned char *buf, int size)
   {
    int n;

    if(WriteFile(Cport[comport_number], buf, size, (LPDWORD)((void *)&n), NULL))
    {
       return(n);
    }

    return(-1);
    }
 }
```

3) This is the receive(),running in a different thread continuosly(polling)

```
int RS232_PollComport(int comport_number, unsigned char *buf, int size)
 {
  int n;

   if(size>4096)  size = 4096;

 /* added the void pointer cast, otherwise gcc will complain about */
 /* "warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict aliasing rules" */

  ReadFile(Cport[comport_number], buf, size, (LPDWORD)((void *)&n), NULL);

  return(n);
  }
```

Comment: Show the relevant code.

Comment: This should *never* happen.  Then again, finding a reliable USB device driver that emulates a serial port correctly is tough shopping.  Just don't set the timeout and pay more attention to the returned number of bytes.  Keep calling ReadFile() until you have enough.

Comment: I'm now using the built-in comport COM1 of my desktop,but still the same problem